# Facebook login button throw Sorry, something went wrong message

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

So basically I am here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/ and I implemented the Full Code Example provided on the page which is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        function statusChangeCallback(response) {  // Called with the results from 
        FB.getLoginStatus().
            console.log('statusChangeCallback');
            console.log(response);                   // The current login status of the person.
            if (response.status === 'connected') {   // Logged into your webpage and Facebook.
                testAPI();  
            } else {                                 // Not logged into your webpage or we are unable to tell.
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
    'into this webpage.';
            }
        }

        function checkLoginState() {               // Called when a person is finished with the Login Button.
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {   // See the onlogin handler
                statusChangeCallback(response);
            });
        }

        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId      : '{app-id}',
                cookie     : true,                     // Enable cookies to allow the server to access the session.
                xfbml      : true,                     // Parse social plugins on this webpage.
                version    : '{api-version}'           // Use this Graph API version for this call.
            });

            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {   // Called after the JS SDK has been initialized.
                statusChangeCallback(response);        // Returns the login status.
            });
        };

        function testAPI() {                      // Testing Graph API after login.  See 
            statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
            console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
    'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
            });
        }
    </script>


    <!-- The JS SDK Login Button -->

    <fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
    </fb:login-button>

    <div id="status">
    </div>

    <!-- Load the JS SDK asynchronously -->
    <script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And it seems that when I press on the Log In button I get a popup showing this message:

```
Sorry, something went wrong.
We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can.
```